# How to remove duplicate rows by considering another row?

Tags: r

I am new with R programming. I have a data set as below. I would like to remove the samples whose C1 column is duplicate and C2 is smaller. How can I do that?

```
myds <-  data.frame(C1 = c(3,5,7,5,3),C2 = c(1,4,3,2,5), C3=c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'))
```

Original data set is

```
C1   C2  C3
--- --- ---
3    1   a
5    4   b
7    3   a
5    2   c
3    5   b
```

I would like my data data set to be as below.

```
C1   C2  C3
--- --- ---
5    4   b
7    3   a
3    5   b
```

Comment: I would go with `library(data.table) ; unique(setDT(myds)[order(-C2)], by = "C1")`

Comment: Or with `base R`  `aggregate(.~C1, df1myds[order(-df1myds$C2),], FUN=head, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(myds, C1) %>% arrange(desc(C2)) %>% slice(1)
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: C1 [3]

     C1    C2     C3
  (dbl) (dbl) (fctr)
1     3     5      b
2     5     4      b
3     7     3      a
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first sort your data frame:

```
myds <- myds[order(myds$C1, -myds$C2),]
```

And then use `duplicated`:

```
myds[!duplicated(myds$C1),]

  C1 C2 C3
5  3  5  b
2  5  4  b
3  7  3  a
```

Comment: You don't need to sort by `C1` really. Just sorting by `-C2` would be enough